# Best practice to a dynamic menu module based on a modular CMS

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Alright, I know the title might be a bit strange. But I don't know how else to put it. Basically it comes down to something simple, but sometimes being a single developer makes you question things and make you want to discuss it with fellow developers.

A quick intro to the problem: I'm about to re-do my CMS based on a popular PHP Framework (Fyi: Laravel is my choice). The CMS will be modular (Blog, Users, Pages, Forms, etc.), but I also want the website navigation to be manageable by the website owners. This is where I started thinking about the best practice to do so.

So far, what I was thinking about is to create an interface "MenuBuilder" that defines the methods that need to be known to generate menu links for a given module. So, let's say my BlogModule has a class BlogMenuBuilder.

The MenuBuilder classes would have a method to build a link based on none or some parameters (like a record ID), a method to generate all links, a method to generate an array of options for a dropdown and so on.

Then the MenuModule would save the classname and optional paramaters to a table, together with the menu location (top, footer, sidebar, etc) and I could call `MenuModule::build('top')`, this function would find all links, sorted ofcourse, and build the links by calling `BlogMenuBuilder::link('type', $optional_parameters);`. Type would in this case be a named route from the Laravel framework. Eventually ,the MenuModule::build() method would cache instead of having to build it again every time.

Am I anywhere near a best practice? I feel like I'm heading in the right direction but since I have no other developers to think this thing thru with I was hoping to get some useable feedback from SO.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I think you should break down your question to: Dynamic menu generation classes for items, generating subitems and page generation (top, footer etc...). My opinion, you should first think how you want your code to look like and them implement it (like BDD if you are familiar)

Comment: That would complete my question to a full module and set-up. But the thing I'm after is just how to "feed" my MenuModule with all possible links from within the system. Not just /blog or /blog/archive but also direct links to articles such as /blog/best-practics-modular-menu-builder

Comment: you could always try and take a look at how popular cms system do it. Like wordpress/drupal and learn from that code.

Comment: I will, but it wouldn't hurt to get some information or ideas out in the public for others to find :)

Comment: Just look at how is this implemented in other CMS built with Laravel as for example [October CMS](https://octobercms.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're pretty much there as far a structure. Based on what I understand from your question (and being that you're using Laravel) I'd approach it like this:

---

### Database

```
Name:    menus
Columns: id | builder | created_at          | updated_at          | deleted_at
         ---------------------------------------------------------------------
     eg. 1  | NULL    | 1985-10-26 01:20:00 | 1985-10-26 01:21:00 | NULL
         2  | blog    | 1985-10-26 01:20:00 | 1985-10-26 01:21:00 | NULL


Name:    links
Columns: id | menu_id | type  | resource_type | resource_id | url                       | created_at          | updated_at          | deleted_at
         -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     eg. 1  | 1       | url   | NULL          | NULL        | http://example.com/blog/1 | 1985-10-26 01:20:00 | 1985-10-26 01:21:00 | NULL
         1  | 2       | route | blog          | 1           | NULL                      | 1985-10-26 01:20:00 | 1985-10-26 01:21:00 | NULL


Name:    meta (or options)
Columns: id | resource_type | resource_id | name     | value
         ---------------------------------------------------
     eg. 1  | menu          | 1           | bg_color | 000000
         2  | link          | 1           | target   | _blank
```

With this table setup you can store menus, links (either a route defined in the relevant builder or a url) and meta/option data for either menus or links.

**Note:** If you wanted to re-use links in multiple menus you could remove the `menu_id` from the `links` table add a `menu_links` table for a [ManyToMany relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) between menus and links

---

### Models

Simple enough, you'd want a model for each table ie. `Menu`, `Link` and `Meta`

---

### Builders

Within the `app` directory of your project I'd place a `Builders` folder and potentially a `MenuBuilders` folder inside that. Using that structure you'd namespace each `Builder` class under `App\Builders\MenuBuilders`.

With each `Builder` class you could then either extend a main `MenuBuilder` class or, depending how much you'll change for each `Builder`, you could `implement` an `interface`. Here's a quick example using an `interface` (if you're not familier with interfaces I'd suggest a look at [Laracasts PHP Bootcamp](https://laracasts.com/series/object-oriented-bootcamp-in-php/episodes/8)):

**MenuBuilderInterface.php**

```
namespace App\Builders\MenuBuilders;

interface MenuBuilderInterface{
    /* 
     * Build function
     *
     * @param object $menu
     */
    public build($menu);
}
```

**BlogMenuBuilder.php**

```
namespace App\Builders\MenuBuilders;

class BlogMenuBuilder implements MenuBuilderInterface {
    /* 
     * Build function
     *
     * @param object $menu
     */
    public build($menu)
    {
        // Here you can now build your menu using
        // the menu instance passed through
    }
}
```

If you didn't want to have to create all the methods contracted in the `interface` then maybe extending a main `MenuBuilder` class works better for you, it really depends on how different you see the menus being and whether you can re-use a lot of methods in a main `MenuBuilder`.

---

### In Practise

So how would you use the above setup? Like you stated in your question, each `menu` defines it's builder in the database so we could create a simple build function in our `Menu` model to call the correct `Builder` class:

**Menu.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Menu extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user's first name.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function build()
    {
        // First we define our namespace and get the builder based on the menu data
        $namespace = 'App\\Builders\\MenuBuilders\\';
        $builder   = !empty($this->builder)? $namespace.ucfirst($this->builder).'MenuBuilder' : $namespace.'MenuBuilder';

        // Then check the builder class defined definitely exists
        // If no, replace with main menu builder class
        $builder = class_exists($builder)? $builder : $namespace.'MenuBuilder';

        // Lastly we call the build method on a new instance of our builder
        // passing in our menu instance
        return new $builder()->build($this);
    }
}
```

Now all we need do in our view is call the build function on our menu instance:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example Site</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        
        <?php
        // Get our blog menu
        // - you would obviously more likely do this in your controller
        $menu = Menu::find(2);
        ?>
        {!! $menu->build() !!}

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

There are always a few different ways you can structure this kind of thing. Inevitably you will figure out what's best for you based on the specific requirements of each outcome you're after, but I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you sir! This is exactly what I had in mind, but I couldn't get it worked out in my head. Great code example and this is exactly what I was after! I guess there can't be that much different methods/ways to get a dynamic menubuilder like this, is there? Because.. this is how I planned to make it but I'd also be curious to know about other methods. Anyway, thanks a lot for the time you took to setup this answer. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just one addition to your answer: I'd let the Menu model loop it's links and call a build() method on the Link model. Since the Menu isn't based on a single module but it can contain links of different models. `blog` would be the men identifier.

Comment: For sure you could basically use the same setup and have different builders for links if you wanted to. The `meta` table can be used to completely customise a link or menu with a set of parameters ie. each `LinkBuilder` could assume a set of meta. That way you keep the base tables clean and get a whole lot of flexibility for each menu/link type.

Comment: Exactly, thanks for your time and effort. Definitly worth the 150 points ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Well as everyone said, do what other big cms'es have done.

So on the UI:
- have a select box of existing menus
- have a button to create a new menu

- when creating or adding a menu
- you will have a button to add a new item
- when new item is clicked you a box with all the pages -->

this part could be complex as how your site is:
- contain static pages: / , /about , /contact
- contain dynamic pages (just like wordpress)
- contain dynamic posts (just like wordpress)
- contain dynamic categories, tags whatever (just like wordpress)
- free input box

Comment: I guess my question isn't formed well enough. It wouldn't hurt anybody to have the information public. Besides.. you are just summing up the things I want to cover in my final solution, how complex my project is can be read in my initial question. There's nothing in your answer that covers anything in my question

Comment: I'm looking for a technical structure on how to get this done. What I've got so far is lined out in my question. I'd like to have others to evaluate or modify what I have so far or share their thoughts and solutions.

Comment: I'm sorry so what exactly are you looking for? do you want code examples? I read the question and that what first come up

Comment: No, it's more focused on the how to structure this. I think I've got it pretty good lined out in my question, but maybe I haven't explained it as good. Code example is always useful, but I'm looking for a structure to be able to create menu's for static pages and dynamic modules. These modules have different data (table, PK's, way to create a lable, etc).